# Blob Data, Reading/Storing in client machine is giving error, but working in developing machine.How.?

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, blob

I created a table with the `BLOB` datatype, in `Oracle` Database,

I tried to retrieve/store data in `BLOB` Datatype using developer Machine, it is working Fine, 
same application was installed on `Oracle Client Machine` that it is giving error like below

```
Object Reference is not set to an instance of an object
Procedure Call or arugument is not valid
```

Code like

```
da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("Select * From DOCUMENTSTAB", OdbcCon)
da.fill(ds,"DOCUMENTSTAB")
```

I am using `VB .NET 2012` with `SYSTEM.DATA.ODBC Connection Type`.

Thanks

Comment: On the network machine, are oracle client drivers available?

Comment: `"Object Reference is not "` Are you sure this is all of the error message text? It does not sound like a valid English sentence.

Comment: Do you have ODAC and ODBC installed on the target machine? looks to me like it is a driver mixup...

And I recommend you using ADO.net - works bettr and faster in most cases..

Comment: All the sql are working fine on client machine, only BLOB datatype TABLE only giving this type of error.

Comment: I guess SYSTEM.DATA.ODBC is also ADO .NET,